# Curl Couldn't resolve host for HTTPS

Tags: linux, ssl, https, curl

I am trying to use curl on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1. When I try to use URL with HTTPS it gives an error message "Couldn't resolve host". But for the same URL when tried with HTTP (http://www.google.lk) response is successful.

```
[root@localhost /]# curl --proxy-user username:password -L -i https://www.google.lk
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.lk'
[root@localhost /]#
```

Can there be anything wrong with my SSL configuration here. Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: I don't think that you got any problems with SSL/TSL. Have you tried 'getent hosts www.google.lk' ? Does the site redirect your web browser to another site when you use https compared with http? What dns-servers do you use, do they give the right answers? 
I do think that you have problems with DNS or generally, name resolvment. Could be that and a combination wit redirect of website to different servers depending on http or https.

Comment: Do you have to use a proxy both for HTTP and HTTPS? How are you configuring the proxy? It looks like curl is only using the proxy for HTTP requests...

Comment: Thank you... Guided by your comments I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was OK after configuring proxy for HTTPS as follows.

```
export https_proxy=http://proxy:8080/
```